# ui: repeat + p: datatable question

Tags: jsf, datatable, primefaces

I displaying multiple `p:datatable` 's through `ui:repeat`, the following code snippet illustrates what I am doing:

```
<ui:repeat id="searchTables"
    value="#{searchBean.mapKeys}"
    var="mapKeys">
         <p:dataTable id="recordTable"
            value="#{searchBean.resultMap[mapKeys].resultList}"
            var="recordTable"
            paginator="true"
            rows="10">
                 <f:facet name="header">
                      <h:outputText value="#{searchBean.resultMap[mapKeys].name}"/>
                 </f:facet>
                    <p:columns value="#{searchBean.resultMap[mapKeys].resultColumns}"
                               var="column"
                               columnIndexVar="colIndex">
                        <f:facet name="header">
                            <p:outputPanel>
                                #{column.header}
                            </p:outputPanel>
                        </f:facet>
                        <h:outputText value="#{recordTable[column.property]}"/><br/>
                    </p:columns>
         </p:dataTable>
 </ui:repeat>
```

I need each individual datatable to have its own paginator, however when my page is displayed only the first datatable gets the paginator and this paginator controls all the other displayed DataTables pages..

Thanks for your attention!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only way I found was to use two p:datatable tags, the parent one with only one column. I couldn't make it work with p:dataList. I guess p:dataList is extending the same bogus class.

Should work with this:

```
<p:datatable id="searchTables"
    value="#{searchBean.mapKeys}"
    var="mapKeys">
    <p:column>
         <p:dataTable id="recordTable"
            value="#{searchBean.resultMap[mapKeys].resultList}"
            var="recordTable"
            paginator="true"
            rows="10">
                 <f:facet name="header">
                      <h:outputText value="#{searchBean.resultMap[mapKeys].name}"/>
                 </f:facet>
                    <p:columns value="#{searchBean.resultMap[mapKeys].resultColumns}"
                               var="column"
                               columnIndexVar="colIndex">
                        <f:facet name="header">
                            <p:outputPanel>
                                #{column.header}
                            </p:outputPanel>
                        </f:facet>
                        <h:outputText value="#{recordTable[column.property]}"/><br/>
                    </p:columns>
         </p:dataTable>
    </p:column>     
 </p:dataTable>
```

Answer (score 3):

This is likely related to [JSF issue 1830](http://java.net/jira/browse/JAVASERVERFACES-1830).

Your best bet is to replace `ui:repeat` by another repeater which does its `UINamingContainer` job better, for example a [`<p:dataList>`](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase-labs/ui/dataListUnordered.jsf) or even another `<p:dataTable>`. The list bullets of `<p:dataList>` can be removed by CSS `list-style-type: none`.

If that also doesn't work, then it's maybe a bug in PrimeFaces `<p:dataTable>` itself.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, neither of the proposed solutions worked, I guess its a bug with `<p:dataTable>` itself :(

Comment: This doesn't take the client ID's into account at all. It's not an `UINamingContainer` component. Besides, it get executed during view build time only, not during view render time.

Comment: Balus hi, when assigning `<p:dataTable id="recordTable"...>` am I before hand assigning a unique ID to all the tables generated by `ui:repeat`?? If so, how can I assign a dynamic ID or similiar? Thanks

Comment: Tried a dynamic ID for both `ui:repeat` and `p:datalist` and `p:datatable` none worked :(